# winrt is it possible to define a brush colour in a resource gallery

Tags: windows-8, styles, windows-runtime

I am trying to define a standard foreground color for the controls in my page.  However, I get the error "An object of the type "System.String" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush".

In myPage.xaml

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
           Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundThemeBrush}" />
```

In StandardStyles.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">

  <x:String x:Key="BackgroundThemeBrush">#484848</x:String>
  <x:String x:Key="ForegroundThemeBrush">#efefef</x:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to define `SolidColorBrush` not `x:String`

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#484848"/>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#efefef"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a SolidColorBrush instead of a x:String for your brush.

Comment: While this might possibly come off as condescending with the "Obviously" at the beginning it is true.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that. But that's just what the quoted error says. Well, maybe except that the OP might not know the string only gets converted to a brush if it is specified directly on a brush property XML attribute.